# Zend select data with where concat

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework

Can anyone help me to fix this?

I want to get data when I set year and month.
And got problem when I try to select data with `where` concat year and month.
That sql query running when I try on my DB but in Zend I got error:

```
$db = Zend_Registry::get('db');

$select = $db->select()
            ->from(array('air'=>$this->_name), 
                array('sumtotal' => new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(air.price) + SUM(inst.cicilan)')));
$select->joinLeft(array('s' => 'store'), 's.id = air.store_id');
$select->joinLeft(array('ar' => 'area'), 'ar.name = s.regional');
$select->joinLeft(array('inst' => 'installment'), 'inst.sn = air.sn');
$select->where('(air.status = ?', A);
$select->orwhere('air.status = ?', B);
$select->orwhere('air.status = ?', C);
$select->orwhere('air.status = ?', D);
$select->orwhere('air.status = ?', E);
$select->orwhere('air.status = ?', F);
$select->orwhere('air.status = ?', G);
$select->orwhere('air.status = ?', H);
$select->orwhere('air.status = ?', I);
$select->orwhere('air.status = ?', J);
$select->orwhere('air.status = ?)', K);
$select->where('ar.id = ?', $area);
$select->where('CONCAT(YEAR(air.date)-MONTH(air.date)) = ?', $year . '-' . $month );
$data = $db->fetchOne($select);
return $data;
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: nothing error reporting.
but i didn't get the value of existing data.
i got "NULL".
@thebluefox

Comment: i think that syntax miss in :
 $select->where('CONCAT(YEAR(air.date)-MONTH(air.date)) = ?', $year . '-' . $month );

because when i just write :
 $select->where('MONTH(air.date) = ?',  $month );

that work.....

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to wrap the concat into a `new Zend_Db_Expr(`, unless the code would be looking for a db column named `CONCAT(YEAR(air.date)-MONTH(air.date))`.

Also, if you are trying to put a dash between the year and month, that would be `CONCAT( YEAR(air.date), '-', MONTH(air.date) )` (see the comas between arguments?).

Lastly, that's ZF1, so you can do `die($select->assemble());` to help with debug.